# spring-boot tomcat security vulnerabilities patching

Tags: spring-boot

Since spring-boot comes with embedded tomcat containers, I was wondering how is the patching being done. If I decide to go for using embedded approach and a security vulnerability has been found out and the tomcat community has released a patch, how do I apply that patch to the embedded tomcat container which comes with the Spring-boot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since it will help to decide to go the traditional route of standalone tomcats v's embedded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications), you can specify any version of Tomcat you want. As long as it's released to the Maven repo, just add the following property to your Maven build properties specifying whatever version you like: `<tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version>`.

See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core for versions currently available in Maven Central.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I could successfully change the tomcat version by changing the properties in the pom.xml